# Maven Build Success, but no result in target folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

For starters, I have not worked with Maven much at all.

I had everything working except for the version not being specified, but when I did specify the Maven version in the pom.xml, it still didn't work.

Note: Every run showed "Build Success" but none put a completed jar file in the target folder, which is what I thought should have happened.

Here is my output from eclipse:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< TromboneSMP:VoluntaryPullFromEternity >----------------
[INFO] Building VoluntaryPullFromEternity 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Roboverse\eclipse-workspace\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\Roboverse\eclipse-workspace\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\target\VoluntaryPullFromEternity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ VoluntaryPullFromEternity ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Roboverse\eclipse-workspace\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\target\VoluntaryPullFromEternity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Roboverse\.m2\repository\TromboneSMP\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\VoluntaryPullFromEternity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Roboverse\eclipse-workspace\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\pom.xml to C:\Users\Roboverse\.m2\repository\TromboneSMP\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\VoluntaryPullFromEternity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.045 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-01T18:46:45-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TromboneSMP</groupId>
  <artifactId>VoluntaryPullFromEternity</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.6.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.7</source>
                  <target>1.7</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>spigot-repo</id>
         <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
           <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.16.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version><!--change this value depending on the version-->
           <type>jar</type>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The output says

`Building jar: C:\Users\Roboverse\eclipse-workspace\VoluntaryPullFromEternity\target\VoluntaryPullFromEternity-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

So if you do not see a JAR in target, you probably need to refresh your Eclipse. Have a look in the Windows Explorer (or some Linux equivalent) if you can find the file.